# How do I combine cast and date max in Redshift?

Tags: date, casting, amazon-redshift

'date' is in timestamp format and has duplicates for the same event id in my event table

if I am doing a subquery getting a max(date) in order to remove duplicate, can I also cast this max as a date instead of timestamp and wrap that in max? hoping to avoid doing unnecessary subqueries thank you.

Comment: Please show us your actual code. Sample data and desired results may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can transform column (by casting or whatever you like) before applying an aggregate function to it. I am not sure how you *remove duplicates*. Have a look at some example transformations using `GROUP BY`

```
with input (dt, v) AS (
    SELECT '2020-12-20T12:00'::timestamp, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-12-20T13:00'::timestamp, 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-12-20T14:00'::timestamp, 30
)
select
       dt::date,
       max(dt),
       max(dt::date),
       max(date_trunc('month', dt)),
       max(last_day(dt)::timestamp),
       avg(v),
       count(*)
from input
group by 1
```

| dt | max | max | max | max | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | 2020-12-20 14:00:00.000000 | 2020-12-20 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000000 | 20 | 3 |